# Is there a way to check if an address is located in the contiguous US with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to enable/disable a shipping option dependent on the customer's shipping address, but working on a platform that limited to vanilla JS. Is there any built in ways I can check an address after grabbing it from the form to see if its located in the 48 contiguous states?

Comment: In core JS no.... Can you just make a list of the states and see if it is in the array?

Comment: @Phix I do not think that is what OP is talking about... `"after grabbing it from the form"`

Comment: What do you mean by "vanilla js"? You can't load any libraries?

Comment: Ah yes, misread. Thanks!

Comment: How is this not a matter of just checking the "state" field and making sure it's a valid state abbreviation and not AK or HI?

Comment: Everything is, ultimately, vanilla JS in the browser. So if some library can do it, so can vanilla JS. But that's not what you want to ask: it looks like what you actually want to ask is "how do I do X in vanilla JS" to which the answer is: it's a little too early to ask on SO for that. SO is here for when you've decided on an approach and started trying writing code for that, and got stuck, and debugging/searching the web hasn't helped you figure things out. The most obvious is of course `states.includes[state]` where `states is a const array of state abbreviations, and `state` the form value

Comment: Also, if there were a "built in" way to check if an address were in the lower 48, it seems to me that the term "vanilla" would be pretty questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have a list of states (either the 48 or the 2) and check to see if it is in that list.

```js
var excludedStates = ["HI", "AK"];

var stateSel = document.querySelector("#state");
stateSel.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  var selection = stateSel.value;
  var isExcluded = excludedStates.includes(selection);
  console.log(selection, isExcluded);
});
```

```html
<select id="state">
  <option value="">Select Your State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have few options:

- have an address input then search through the inputted value to extract the state
- have everything pre-determined, i.e. every detail of the address (street, house number, state, province, ...etc) all created in a separate input so you guarantee that the same data structure would be fetched every time. this would require setting up a lot of predefined values for each of those, so would take a lot of research on your part for some of the forms (county name, valid postal codes, ...etc)
- your third option, and best option if you ask me, is to use this library [address-validator](https://github.com/mkoryak/address-validator). i know you don't want to use npm in the project, but you can clone the repo and build the static files and use the generated js file in your project by adding it as a source for `<script>` tag. of course you would have to follow the documentation for library but it is easy enough and provide a response with state name after validation for you to check.